# What is wrong with doctrine2 entity association

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

Elloo, I have two doctrine entities and am trying to do left join however i'm getting a message "Error: Class GR\Entity\AccountEvents has no association named Accounts". i have looked at other solutions on stackoverflow however none has helped.

here is my code

```
<?php
namespace GR\Entity;
/**
 * 
 * @Table(name="accounts")
 * @Entity
 */
class Accounts
{
    /**
     *
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer",nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=255,nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=255,nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=255,nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime",nullable=false)
     * @var datetime
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AccountEvents", mappedBy="Accounts") 
     */ 
    private $accountevents;  

    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    public function __set($property,$value)
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
}
```

..and

```
<?php
namespace GR\Entity;
/**
 * 
 * @Table(name="account_events")
 * @Entity
 */
class AccountEvents
{
    /**
     *
     * @var integer $id
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer",nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
      * @var Accounts $accounts
      *
      * @Column(name="account_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
      * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Accounts", inversedBy="accountevents")
      * @JoinColumn(name="accounts_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    private $accounts;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=255,nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    private $event;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime",nullable=false)
     * @var datetime
     */
    private $created_at;


    public function __get($property)
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    public function __set($property,$value)
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
}
```

..and my query

```
$query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
                       ->select('a, e')
                       ->from('GR\Entity\AccountEvents', 'e')
                       ->leftJoin('e.Accounts', 'a')
                       ->query();


$results = $query->getResult();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should move the answer into an Answer. You can - and probably should - even accept your own Answer.

Comment: I think you're mixing concepts. You should not have foreign keys on objects. More over, it looks like you have many-to-many since and event have "$accounts". But I would expect that an event have just one account. So "$account", not "$accounts". Why you entity's name is called "Accounts" instead of just "Account"? Why you're not using the plain DQL instead of query builder? Too many things to fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it and here is the solution below (i'm using ZF 1.11, doctrine 2 and nolasnowball library)

In Accounts entity change

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="AccountEvents", mappedBy="accounts")
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $accountevents;
```

In AccountEvents entity change

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Accounts")
 * @JoinColumn(name="accounts_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @var GR\Entity\Accounts
 **/
private $accounts;
```

To fetch resultset

```
$query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->select('a, e')
                   ->from('GR\Entity\Accounts', 'a')
                   ->leftJoin('a.accountevents', 'e');

$results = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

here is the full code http://pastie.org/3626654